# PHP: Run Functions Only After Checking Variable After Each

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have a series of functions that I'd like to run.  At the end of each function, it either sets a variable TRUE or FALSE.  What I'd like to do is break the series if the variable sets to TRUE.

For example.  I have the following:

```
$done = false;

step1(); // Sets $done to false
step2(); // Sets $done to false
step3(); // Sets $done to true
step4(); // Because step3() set $done to true, I wan't step4() to NOT run.
```

Of course if step3() returns false, I'd like to keep going and run step4().

I know I'll need to use a while, switch, and/or a break.  I'm just unclear on how to set this up.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not much clear to me, but if your functions return booleans, you can try:

```
step1() || step2() || step3() || step4();
```

The operator `||` only evaluate the second operand if the first is false.

Comment: Thanks for that @tassoevan, that's good to know.  However the reason why that won't work is because the functions themselves don't return anything.  Continuing or not needs to depend on an outside variable.  However, knowing this...I can certainly tweak it to work like you've shown.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by using a simple `if` statement if you want.

```
$done = false;
$done = step1();  // each function returns true or false
if (!$done)
     {
      $done = step2();
     }
if (!$done)
     {
      $done = step3();
     }
if (!$done)
     {
      $done = step4();
     }
```

correct me if there is any mistakes.

Comment: Thanks @Shabeer.  That's actually how I have it running right now.  The actual application is a bit more complex than what I gave in my example, making a series of if statements really messy.  There's got to be a cleaner way.

Comment: You can improve this with a array of function names and a loop with call_user_func. Just put a `if` test to break the loop on desired stop condition, `$done == true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $done = false;

function step1($done){
    if($done===false){
        //proceed step 2
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
function step2($done){
    if($done===false){
        //proceed step 3
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
function step3($done){
    if($done===false){
        //proceed step 4
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
function step4($done){
    if($done===false){
        //finish
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very straight forward, probably similar to the form you have so far.

You could create an array with callbacks of your functions and consume them while `$done` is `false` and there are still functions to consume:

```
$doFunctions = ['step1', 'step2', ... , 'stepN'];
$done = false;

while (!$done && $doFunctions)
{
    $function = array_shift($doFunctions);
    call_user_func($function);    
}
```

As this shows, no `switch` and no `break` needed, because you have a simple condition here.

Another alternative would be to "make" the functions return something by wrapping it inside a closure and keep the `$done` as a reference (context), then return it:

```
$done = false;
$call = function ($function) use (&$done) {
    $function();
    return $done;
}

$call('step1')
    || $call('step2') 
    || $call('step3') 
    || $call('step4')
;
```

It depends a bit of what you actually need to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

So perhaps my question was misunderstood, but after a while I realized that a try/catch block with exceptions was exactly what I was after.  Here is roughly what I ended up doing.

First I set up my functions to throw exceptions on errors.

```
function step1() {
    // do awesome stuff
    if ($errorInStep1) {
        throw new Exception('There was an error in step 1.');
    }
}

function step2() {
    // do awesome stuff
    if ($errorInStep2) {
        throw new Exception('There was an error in step 2.');
    }
}

function step3() {
    // do awesome stuff
    if ($errorInStep3) {
        throw new Exception('There was an error in step 3.');
    }
}

function step4() {
    // do awesome stuff
    if ($errorInStep4) {
        throw new Exception('There was an error in step 4.');
    }
}
```

So now if there is an error in each of the functions, the script will throw an exception.

Then I wrap those functions in a try/catch block.  The script will try to go through each statement, and if something throws and exception...it will stop right there.  Perfect.

```
try {
    step1();
    step2();
    step3();
    step4();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```